# Oracle apex control break on interactive report doesn't sum columns properly

Tags: report, oracle-apex

Help! I have a demo in two hours that's supposed to showcase Oracle Apex's reporting features. I'm running into an issue with the control break feature not properly summing my columns. The "total" column's data type is a number with the built in apex format mask of 'FML999G999G999G999G990D00'. The aggregation works when I'm looking at the report with no control break. But as soon as I apply a control break, it seems to break my aggregation by displaying the sum as the first total in the control break. I've tried taking away the format mask, using to_number on my column, taking away my extra "Status = Singleton", nothing seems to work.

[image]

Comment: If I convert my "Created Date" into a string via to_char, the aggregation seems to work while having a control break on the string "Created Date". But now I won't be able to sort by created date correctly because it's just a string.

Comment: Does CREATED DATE contain time component as well? What if you - in interactive report's query - apply `SELECT TRUNC(CREATED_DATE) as CREATED_DATE, ...`?

Comment: This was in fact my issue. I was formatting the page item to cut off the time component, but the actual data still held the time. When I trunc the page item, the control break works as intended. Much appreciated!

Comment: You're welcome; I'm glad you made it work.